# How to silently print a RDLC

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, rdlc

I am developing a Winforms app, following this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/XmlReports04182007115639AM/XmlReports.aspx) to make a report out of XML file. Now I need to print it on a specific type of printer `'BIXOLON'` and specific type of paper, I need to include this information then perform a print.

I tried to copy and paste this code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx), but I got an error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.

on that line

```
    private void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
       /*>>>>>*/ report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
    }
```

I don't know how to print directly to the printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from MSDN use `PrintDocument` to print report.
Simply set this property to use a specific printer:

```
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "NameOfYourPrinter"
```

If you get an error on `Report.Render` maybe there is a problem in your rdlc file. Can you view it in a ReportViewer without error?